# legend does not correspond to scale_fill_manual colors (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to make a plot with two groups (shape and color, respectively), but the legend in "Cap W" does not correspond to `scale_fill_manual` colors.

[image]

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                 y = 4:8,
                 z = c("z1", "z1", "z2", "z2", "z3"),
                 w = c("w2", "w3", "w4", "w1", "w1"))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, shape = z, fill = w)) +
    geom_point(size = 6) +
    scale_shape_manual(name = "Cap Z", values = c(21, 22, 24)) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Cap W", values = c("black", "grey30", "grey60", "white")) +
    theme_bw()
```

Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks Ben! The other answer solved my problem! What should I do now? Should I exclude my question?